# How to create a h2 database from some fields of a CSV file

Tags: java, database, csv, h2

i would like to create a new embedded h2 database from a CSV file.
Here is the snippet of the csv file

> Country,City,AccentCity,Region,Population,Latitude,Longitude
>
> ad,aixovall,Aixovall,06,,42.4666667,1.4833333
>
> ad,andorra,Andorra,07,,42.5,1.5166667
>
> ad,andorra la vella,Andorra la Vella,07,20430,42.5,1.5166667
>
> ad,andorra-vieille,Andorra-Vieille,07,,42.5,1.5166667
>
> ad,andorre,Andorre,07,,42.5,1.5166667

I don't want to retrieve all the fields of the csv file. Actually, i want them all except the *City* and *Region* fields.

And further, i want to insert the content of the csv file into the database ONLY IF the content of *POPULATION* is not empty.

Thus, in the csv example above, we must only insert the 3rd row into the h2 table WORLDCITIES because its 'population' field is indicated.

Here is a snippet of code i wrote. But, as you can see, it is not enough yet:

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, connectionProps);
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.execute("CREATE TABLE WORLDCITIES"
        + " AS SELECT COUNTRY, ACCENTCITY, POPULATION, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE"
        + " FROM CSVREAD('snippet.csv'));
```

And if i understand correctly, CSVREAD create the fields using the VARCHAR type, but i want the things like this:

COUNTRY VARCHAR(3),  ACCENTCITY VARCHAR(40), POPULATION FLOAT, LATITUDE FLOAT, LONGITUDE FLOAT

Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add the column definitions in the CREATE TABLE [as](http://h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#csv) [documented](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#create_table) and combine this with a WHERE clause. Please note using CREATE TABLE AS SELECT is a bit faster than separate CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO statements (not sure if speed is very important for you):

```
CREATE TABLE WORLDCITIES(
  COUNTRY VARCHAR(3), 
  ACCENTCITY VARCHAR(40), 
  POPULATION FLOAT, 
  LATITUDE FLOAT, 
  LONGITUDE FLOAT)
AS SELECT 
  COUNTRY, 
  ACCENTCITY, 
  POPULATION, 
  LATITUDE, 
  LONGITUDE
FROM CSVREAD('snippet.csv') 
WHERE POPULATION IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, finally i did use used your solution !

Answer (score 3):

finally, i proceeded like this as you adviced.
I only put the parts of the code which i think is more related to the question :)

`

```
private final String createTableString = ""
    + "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + _tableName
    + " ("
    + "id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, "
    + "country VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL, "
    + "city VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, "
    + "region VARCHAR (5) NOT NULL, "
    + "population FLOAT NOT NULL, "
    + "latitude FLOAT NOT NULL, "
    + "longitude FLOAT NOT NULL, "
    + "PRIMARY KEY(id)"
    + " );";

private final String insertString = ""
    + "INSERT INTO " + _tableName
    + " (country, city, region, population, latitude, longitude) "
    + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)"
    + ";";

public void go() throws IOException, SQLException {

    loadDriver();
    Connection conn = null;
    Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
    connectionProps.put("user", "");
    connectionProps.put("password", "");
    String connectionURL = _protocol + _subprotocol + _dbName + _dbSettings;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, connectionProps);
        logger.info("Connected to {} database.", _dbName);

        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        Savepoint savept1 = conn.setSavepoint();

        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        try {
            stmt.execute(createTableString);
            logger.info("The table '{}' created successfully", _tableName);
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            logger.error("Error while creating the table '{}'", _tableName);
            printSQLException(sqle);
        }

        PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(insertString);
        _allStatements.add(pstmt);
        /* rs:                           pstmt:
         * 1 -> COUNTRY                  
         * 2 -> CITY                     1 -> COUNTRY
         * 3 -> ACCENTCITY               2 -> CITY
         * 4 -> REGION                   3 -> REGION
         * 5 -> POPULATION               4 -> POPULATION
         * 6 -> LATITUDE                 5 -> LATITUDE
         * 7 -> LONGITUDE                6 -> LONGITUDE
         */
        rs = Csv.getInstance().read(_csvFileName, null, _csvCharset);
        int rowCount = 0;
        while (rs.next()) {
            if (rs.getFloat(5) != 0) { // If population is not null.
                pstmt.setString(1, rs.getString(1)); // country
                pstmt.setString(2, rs.getString(3)); // city (accentcity in reality)
                pstmt.setString(3, rs.getString(4)); // region
                pstmt.setFloat(4, rs.getFloat(5));   // population
                pstmt.setFloat(5, rs.getFloat(6));   // latitude
                pstmt.setFloat(6, rs.getFloat(7));   // longitude
                pstmt.addBatch();
                rowCount ++;
            }
        }
        int[] rowsUpdated = pstmt.executeBatch();
        for (int i=0; i<rowsUpdated.length; i++) {
            if (rowsUpdated[i] == -2) {
                logger.error("Execution {}: unknown number of rows inserted.", i);
                logger.error("Rolling back ...");
                conn.rollback(savept1);
            } else {
                logger.trace("Successful: execution {}, {} rows updated !", i, rowsUpdated[i]);
            }
        }
        conn.commit();
    }
    finally { // release all open resources to avoid unnecessary memory usage.
```

....`

Thanks!

Comment: @Thomas Mueller's example is more succinct. A similar approach can be used with [INSERT](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#insert), too.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `read()` method of the H2 class [`Csv`](http://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/tools/Csv.html), and iterate through the `ResultSet`, inserting the desired rows as you find them.

Comment: @Thomas Mueller: Thanks for commenting on this; your approach is better.